# Iterate based on number provided in json

Tags: dust.js

I'm getting a number back from json that represents the number of divs I need to create in my template.  Is there a way to iterate and create the elements in the template based on this number using dust?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Dust only iterates over arrays. So, you could pass an array of the length you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/yXx5L/2/.

```
real_no
```

is the number of times the template would be iterated.

```
based_on_number
```

is a helper method that iterates the template for `real_no` times.